# c++ doxygen + breathe tables

Tags: doxygen, python-sphinx

I have a large c++ project documented with doxygen. I want to use breathe to make nicer manuals. The in-source documentation often contain tables such as this:

```
/**
 * @var somevar
 * @brief some variable
 * @defgroup somegroup Some Group
 * @details This stores some value in some variable
 * | English | German | Parameters |
 * |---------|--------|------------|
 * | `content of somevar %%s in english.\n` | `content of somevar %%s in German\n` |`<Battery percent>` |
 */
```

I generate the xml docs in `build/xml` with doxygen and run sphinx to generate the docs.

```
doxygen Doxyfile
make html
make latexpdf
```

The directory structure looks like this:

```
├── build
├── Doxyfile
├── make.bat
├── Makefile
└── source
    ├── conf.py
    ├── index.rst
    ├── somegroup.rst
    ├── _static
    └── _templates
```

All works fine, documents are created, but the table is missing. I can see the table in the `build/xml/group___somegroup.xml`. The table is also shown in the html output of doxygen. But it is missing in the html and pdf generated by sphinx + breathe.

I cannot find any reference that doxygen tables are not supported by breathe. What am I missing?

Comment: Which version of doxygen?

Comment: I'm using doxygen v1.8.14, breathe 4.9.1 and sphinx 1.7.5. default python version is 3, but I think there is some mechanism to choose the python version the modules want.

Comment: Rereading question, so doxygen supplies the information but breathe does not pick up the information, so probably a breathe problem.

Comment: obviously breathe does not understand the <table> property in the generated xml. It understands lists, verbatim etc. A warning would have been nice about <table> not beeing implemented by breathe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[exhale](https://exhale.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mastering_doxygen.html#tables) has some useful info:

> Tables
>
> Tip
>
> Everything from here on may cause issues with Doxygen. Use the \rst verbatim environment described in the Doxygen Aliases section.
>
> Use grid tables!!!

The will guide you to [their doxygen aliases](https://exhale.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mastering_doxygen.html#doxygen-aliases):

> ALIASES
>
> In particular, the two aliases Exhale provides come from Breathe, and allow you to wield full-blown reStructuredText (including directives, grid tables, and more) in a “verbatim” environment. The aliases as sent to Doxygen:

```
# Allow for rst directives and advanced functions e.g. grid tables
ALIASES  = "rst=\verbatim embed:rst:leading-asterisk"
ALIASES += "endrst=\endverbatim"
```

> This allows you to do something like this in your code:

```
/**
 * \file
 *
 * \brief This file does not even exist in the real world.
 *
 * \rst
 * There is a :math:`N^2` environment for reStructuredText!
 *
 * +-------------------+-------------------+
 * | Grid Tables       | Are Beautiful     |
 * +===================+===================+
 * | Easy to read      | In code and docs  |
 * +-------------------+-------------------+
 * | Exceptionally flexible and powerful   |
 * +-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
 * | Col 1 | Col 2 | Col 3 | Col 4 | Col 5 |
 * +-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
 *
 * \endrst
 */
```

Not so nice, but I can live with that.

Comment: This works, but the RST table (obviously) renders as mangled text if you try to generate HTML from the Doxygen.  The best workaround I could find was to use @if statements to conditionally compile one version or the other, which is awkward, but works.

Answer (score 0):

@user1283043 shared a good answer, but it's incomplete if you need to both generate output via Sphinx (where the answer works) and directly from Doxygen (where it doesn't).  The solution I came up with involves the use of Doxygen @if statements to conditionally compile two versions of the same table.

For the Doxyfile used to generate the Sphinx output, include the previously mentioned aliases:

```
ALIASES  = "rststar=@verbatim embed:rst:leading-asterisk"
ALIASES += "endrst=@endverbatim"
```

Then enable a *SPHINX* section that the Doxygen markup can check for:

```
ENABLED_SECTIONS = SPHINX
```

With this in place, you can adjust your Doxygen table markup appropriately:

```
/**
 * @brief Documentation with a table in it
 *
 * These are the allowed values:
 *
 * @if SPHINX
 * @rststar
 * +-------+----------+---------------------------+
 * | Value | Range    | Description               |
 * +=======+==========+===========================+
 * | FOO   | 0..27    | The range for a FOO value |
 * +-------+----------+---------------------------+
 * | BAR   | 91..1372 | The range for a BAR value |
 * +-------+----------+---------------------------+
 * @endrst
 * @else
 * Value | Range    | Description
 * ----- | :------: | -------------------------
 * FOO   | 0..27    | The range for a FOO value
 * BAR   | 91..1372 | The range for a BAR value
 * @endif
 */
```

It's a bit ugly and awkward, because you need to enter the same text twice, but you get a proper table both when compiled through Doxygen and when compiled through Sphinx/Breathe.